# Does CREATE/REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW in PostgreSQL use the parallel planner?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, materialized-view, parallelism

I am wondering whether `CREATE` (with data) or `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` uses the parallel planner. When I `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the query by itself (any query with parallel potential works here) without creating the materialized view, it shows that said query is parallel aware, and executing said query by itself shows multiple processors active using standard Linux tools like top.

Conversely, executing the query within a `REFRESH` or `CREATE` materialized view wrapper, does not show multiple processes, and using `EXPLAIN` on `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` shows a query that is not parallel aware. Is this intentional behavior and why? I was not able to find any information on this. (PostgreSQL 10.5 on CentOS 7)

Checked that this behavior is the same when using `CREATE TABLE AS` and `SELECT INTO`. Is there any way to write a table using parallelism?

Is there any workaround I can use to `CREATE TABLE` using parallelism without first outputting the results of the query to a file? Such as somehow splitting the query into several hundred equal parts defined by an aggregation variable in the data, followed by a specified number of cores in parts getting `INSERT`'ed in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism for `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` was [added in Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.6.4).

Parallelism for `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` was [added in Postgres 14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html).